# How to decorate GetOrderPreviewHandler in Prestashop 1.7.8

Tags: prestashop, handler

I would like to modify the [getProductDetails](https://github.com/PrestaShop/PrestaShop/blob/develop/src/Adapter/Order/QueryHandler/GetOrderPreviewHandler.php#L203) function of the [GetOrderPreviewHandler](https://github.com/PrestaShop/PrestaShop/blob/develop/src/Adapter/Order/QueryHandler/GetOrderPreviewHandler.php#L57) in Prestashop. So i can add the ordered product customization value to the quick order preview in the backoffice of prestashop.
I found a manual at the [prestashop developer reference](https://devdocs.prestashop.com/1.7/modules/concepts/services/#decorate-the-service) and read the symfony docs.
But can't find the right way to do this within prestashop through the services.yml.
Does anyone have any experience with this and can point me in the right direction?